# Is there a jQuery script to display Twitter feed with auto-refresh?

Tags: jquery, twitter, drop-down-menu, feed

This question may be for someone familiar with creating pipes in Yahoo! Pipes.  But I'm looking for a jQuery script that will display 4 tweets that will drop down automatically every 5 seconds when new tweets are posted AND that ends in a specific hash tag.  It'd be great too if I could filter out bad words.

Know of any scripts out there that will do the trick?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go... a jQ twitter ticker script...

http://www.zazar.net/developers/jquery/ztwitterfeed/

Answer (score 0):

You could hack up an existing plugin with a setTimeout so that it gets called every x time interval.

I've used http://tweet.seaofclouds.com/ which is pretty easy to set up.

Hope this gets you started.